# PMA export with all attributes in CREATE TABLE

Tags: mariadb, phpmyadmin, export

This is the default PMA output of an export:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `fk_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

ALTER TABLE `foo`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `foo`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `foo`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `foo_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_id`) REFERENCES `bar` (`id`),

...
```

Is there a way to get an export where all of the following `ALTER TABLE` are *merged* into the `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shows all changes you have made, as you can see in the example

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE `bar` (`id` int(11) UNSIGNED,PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `fk_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

ALTER TABLE `foo`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `foo`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `foo`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `foo_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_id`) REFERENCES `bar` (`id`);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SHOW CREATE  TABLE foo;

| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
| ----- | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| foo   | CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fk_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `foo_ibfk_1` (`fk_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `foo_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_id`) REFERENCES `bar` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wUqVKNZy96RjR7hTk3md7o/13)

Comment: Yes, the command shows indeed what I asked for but my question was, how to enable it in PMA. I think it's not possible. As I need only the structure I can live with it. +1 & accepted. Thx

Comment: phpmyadmin works like mysql 5.7 and this shows all changes like the show in the export to sql.